# NP++: Regular expression to find square brackets

Tags: expression, notepad++

How can I search for a string like this:

> [safdsadsadsadad]

Criterion is: Opening square bracket and the first closing square bracket after ist. And replace the complete string by nothing (thats clear). My problem is: How to search for squre brackets as strings, as square brackets have a meta-meaning for regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++ you can try this:
`\[\w+\]`, you can escape special scharacters with `\`

Answer (score 4):

Have a try with:

Find what: `\[[^[\]]*\]`
Replace with: `Nothing`